# Is there a way to create a launchctl service using snap?

Tags: macos, launchd

I am using snap to create a systemd service on Linux - I am wondering if there is a way to use snap to create a launchctl service on MacOS?

Comment: You might need to document this a bit. For sure linking to snap. If you’ve gotten some research or care about one version of macOS, editing those details in as well might help. No need to edit, simple is good too.

Comment: yeah, i did some googling, doesn't appear to be a way to create something on macos using snap, but keeping my fingers crossed, idk

Comment: Good thing, I've seen questions sit here for 8 months and then out of the blue, get an amazing answer. For now you can brew it up on macOS and linux 

Comment: well, it turns out snap won't work for my use case. I need a level of access to the host machine that snap processes don't have access to, since they run in multipass VMs/Containers. Kinda lame, but that's how snap packages run.